# Why does DateTime() not define midnight?

Tags: c#

The following lines of code in C#:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine("Time: "+t.ToLocalTime());
```

output the following:

```
Time: 01/01/2020 01:00:00
```

shouldn't it be midnight ?

```
Time: 01/01/2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: I see - I am in CEST+1 (Berlin/Zurich).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.ToLocalTime()` does the following according to the docs:

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to local time.

You are probably in a time zone with +1 hour shift to GMT normal time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the `DateTime` initialized relative to the local timezone, pass `DateTimeKind.Local`:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
```